# Select file format .MTL (support Object format) in React Native (IOS)

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, mtl-file

I am currently working with AR(Viro) in React-Native. I'm using a 3d OBJ format to display 3d model in AR View. The problem is I can't pick the file with format .MTL in IOS. When I check the format of MTL file in IOS, it doesn't show anything and force me to Google Drive. I was looking around for a month and didn't come up with any idea. Please help me.

The library I used is [react-native-document-picker](https://github.com/Elyx0/react-native-document-picker). I put the option `AllFile` but it not help.

Comment: Can you try this? `react-native-webgl` https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webgl

Comment: I don't have problem with 3D obj. The problem is I can't choose MTL file in document picker